# Ошибка при использовании scanf(const char* , ...)

Tags: c++, input, scanf, build-error

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    const char *c = "";

    scanf(c);

    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции выводится ошибка:

```
--------------------------------

warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

    scanf(c);
          ^
1 warning generated.
```

### IDE предлагает решение, но оно не помогает:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    const char *c = "";

    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security"

    scanf(c);

    #pragma clang diagnostic pop

    return 0;
}
```

- Если кто-нибудь знает решение, просьба помочь
- Либо вариант заменить scanf (кроме cin)

Comment: [man 3 scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)  читайте первоисточники

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первым аргументом scanf принимает флаг, обозначающий формат принимаемых данных. Допустимы следующие флаги:

- %c: считывает один символ

  %d: считывает десятичное целое число

  %i: считывает целое число в любой системе (десятичной,
  шестнадцатеричной, восьмеричной)

  %u: считывает положительное целое число

  %e: считывает число с плавающей точкой в экспоненциальной форме

  %E: считывает число с плавающей точкой в экспоненциальной форме с
  заглавным символом экспоненты

  %f: считывает число с плавающей точкой

  %F: считывает число с плавающей точкой

  %g: считывает число с плавающей точкой

  %G: считывает число с плавающей точкой

  %o: считывает восьмеричное число

  %x: считывает шестнадцатеричное число

  %X: считывает шестнадцатеричное число

  %s: считывает строку

  %%: считывает символ процента

Рабочий пример:

```
    int age;

    printf("Input your age:");

    scanf("%d", &age);
```

Вы же передали в качестве флага пустую строку. Очевидно, что это не работает

Подробнее о работе функции можете посмотреть [тут](https://metanit.com/cpp/c/2.14.php).

Comment: а как правильнее назвать: ` "флаг"` или все же `"формат"`?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если обратиться к англоязычным источникам, то там это зовут `format specifier`, что можно перевести как `спецификатор` (или `описатель`) формата http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/. Так, наверное, правильнее. Но в целом, я считаю, как ни назвать, главное, чтобы смысл был ясен. Поэтому я написал ответ своими словами, как мне показалось, будет наиболее понятно обывателю

Comment: Александр, просто под  словом "флаг" понимается  несколько иная суть, чем строка,  предназначенная для выполнения по некоторому то формату .  Верно, смысль ответа ясен,  но лучше  вещи называть своими именами,  Это не замечание, а  обсуждение о разнице сущностей.